# Reducing memory usage with large models

Tags: memory, netlogo

I'm trying to set up a model for calculating proximity values for large environments (more than 500x500 patches) with many targets (ca 100). The proximity values from a patch to all the targets are kept in a list at each patch.

The script below (fills the lists with random numbers) has inexplicably high memory usage. 500x500x100 integer values (4 bytes each) should take up about 100 MB of space. When I run the script the Netlogo application increases from ca 200 MB (when the program is started) to about 1500 MB.

What could I do to reduce the memory usage? Is the problem in my implementation or the overhead that Netlogo has for lists?

```
patches-own[ proximity_list ] ; The list to hold proximity values
let num_targets 100 ; Number of targets to calculate proximity values for
let largest_value 100000 ; The largest value the list can contain

ask patches[
    set proximity_list []
    let i 0
    while [i < num_targets] [
        set test_list (lput (random largest_value) test_list)
        set i i + 1
    ]
]
```

PS I tried the same thing with the Arrays extension, it reduces memory usage a bit (ca 1300MB) but still does not solve the problem.

Comment: One of the NetLogo developers can likely answer this definitively, but there are perhaps two things going on here.  First, NetLogo uses 64-bit doubles internally, 8 bytes rather than 4.  But also, lists are not mutable in NetLogo so I suspect that each time you `lput' a new list is created and it takes a while for the garbage collector to get rid of the discarded copies.  They'd add up pretty quickly. But arrays are mutable, so I'm not sure why they wouldn't avoid this problem.  Are you creating an array with an initial length of 100 and then using replace-item to fill it in with real numbers?

Comment: Yes, I tried with arrays and now tried it again to be extra sure. Mem usage is about the same still, ca 1400 MB. Also kept the Netlogo application open long after as well, garbage collection doesn't seem to do anything either, the memory usage stays the same.

The code i used is [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/07094f557126c4601f21cfb396e0ecb6)

Comment: If you simply set up the arrays from the list, memory usage goes up by about 200K, and with smaller arrays, less. It is repeatedly running array:set that ups the memory usage so much, and particularly when using random as opposed to just a large number. So I think the issue is not the array size, but NetLogo (or jvm) internals that are driving up the memory size.